# ReportViewer in Winform Panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, reportviewer

I am busy fiddling with the microsoft reportviewer vs2010. 
Is it possible to embed the reportviewer inside a Windows Forms Panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 
You can just drag and drop the reportviewer control onto a windows form.
Install the reportviewer control component (I think the latest one is version 11, choose from toolbox controls, data tab and add the reportviewer to your form.